# XQuery Comparing 2 lists of number

Tags: xquery

Given 2 xml file that contain a list of number in each.

```
<list1>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    ...
</list1>

list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
list2 = [1,4,6,2,8]
```

I only want the number in list1 that are greater than all of the number in list2, how can I do that?

I tried this, but it only return the number if it is greater than one of the number in list2 and not the entire list.

```
for $x in doc("list1.xml")/item
    for $y in doc("list2.xml")/item
        where ($x > $y) 
return $x
```

Thanks in advance, newbie in xquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XQuery 3.0 you can use `fn:for-each`, which makes a nicer syntax in my opinion. So for each item in `$list1` it checks whether there is an item in `$list2` which is larger.

```
let $list1 := (1 to 10)
let $list2 := (1, 4, 6, 2, 8)
return for-each($list1, function($l) {
  if (for-each($list2, function($x) {$l > $x}) = false())
  then ()
  else $l
})
```

If you just have XQuery 1.0, this should work as well and does basically the same:

```
let $list1 := (1 to 10)
let $list2 := (1, 4, 6, 2, 8)
for $l in $list1
where not((
  for $f in $list2
  return $l > $f
) = false())
return $l
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I have misunderstood the question, but it seems to me that there is a much simpler and more efficient solution using a single predicate which does not require any explicit loops:

```
xquery version "1.0";

let $list1 := (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10)
let $list2 := (1, 4, 6, 2, 8)

let $max2 := max($list2)

return

    $list1[. gt $max2]
```

I would also like to make it clear to @ou-ye a little about XQuery terminology. At present there is no such thing as a List structure in XQuery, the closest thing is a Sequence which is constructed using `(` and `)`.